# Gtk Z-ordering mess

Tags: gtk, gtk2, z-order

I have the following structure of widgets: 
`w: GtkWindow
    f: GtkFixed
        da: GtkDrawingArea
        cf: GtkFixed
            cda: GtkDrawingArea
            i: GtkIcon
            s1: GtkAdjustment
            s2: GtkAdjustment`

They are listed in order of insertion (gtk_container_add to insert into w, gtk_fixed_put for all other isertions). cf fully overlaps da after all widgets are placed and sized; cda, i, s1 and s2 do not overlap and cover a contiguous area.
When this structure is exposed, the order of appearance, top to bottom, is as follows:
    `cda over
    da over
    s1, s2, i`

da is masked to only receive expose signals; da visually obscures s1 and s2, but mouse events are sent and handled by s1 and s2 - the event kinda "fall thru" da.

**What the heck? How come Gtk sticks da INSIDE a sibling container widget and IN BETWEEN the children of the sibling?** (that makes then nephews and neices i guess haha :)

What I'm trying to get is for da to be the "backdrop" of the window w; several sibling GtkFixed will eventually be inserted into f, possibly with some gaps between them, and I need to draw on the backdrop da, and I'm totally fine with parts of da being obscured by other widgets. I do not want to create multiple DrawingAreas for each gap.

I guess what I'm describing is a usual Z-ordering, which for some reason does not work in my case. Oh, and I'm bound to use Gtk 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since no guru was able to help my newbie problem, I had to become a guru, study sources and develop a solution by myself. Here it is.

The problem is that in Gtk, widget structure does not correspond to window structure. By default, GtkFixed does not have a corresponding window, and thus in my example the window structure was as follows:

`w: GtkWindow
    f: GtkFixed (* no window *)
    da: GtkDrawingArea
    cf: GtkFixed (* no window *)
    cda: GtkDrawingArea
    i: GtkIcon
    s1: GtkAdjustment
    s2: GtkAdjustment`

Basically, flat. So, all widget windows were inserted into w.window in arbitrary order, which led to *da* being shown between it's "nephews".

Thus, the solution is to tell GtkFixed to have a window of it's own:

`cf := gtk_fixed_new();
gtk_widget_set_has_window(cf, 1)`

Answer (score -1):

If you use GtkFixed then you deserve to get "What the heck" behaviour. Never ever ever use it! It breaks accessibility. It breaks UI design rules. Nesting them is a nightmare. Your friends will disown you and your dog will leave diarohea in your slippers. If you want to defy modern coding practice, use a GOTO or dynamically modify your code segment, just never use GtkFixed.

Comment: Paul, you're too quick to judge before knowning why I've chosen to use GtkFixed.

And as for "modern coding practices" - **to hell with them**! Whatevert they are, they make programs fat! I am extending a fully-featured text editor and IDE (compiler+debugger+linker) that operates just under 1MB or RAM (yes, MB, not GB!) - modern systems provide the same functionality but eat up thousands of times (literally!) more resources.

Comment: As it seemt to me, Gtk is just Z-order agnostic. It would be good programming practise to just deliberately and explicitly state it somewhere in the docs, rather than provide a widget and strongly discourage from using it! I've read all the cautions against using GtkFixed, and nothing was specific enough to mention that there's no notion of Z-order.

Comment: In fact, I'm just curious what kind of modern coding practice you have to use in implementation to display ("map") a widget in-between it's sibling's children! Simple dynamic lists or arrays won't suffice - you have to be more crooked than that! And, exposition and mouse events are obviously handled differently. Wow!! No, I'll stick with old programming practices that read, **Make it as simple as possible, but not simpler**. This is at least 100 years old. Goes back to Einstein.

Comment: Well, use vim. Just loading GTK+ (even in its version 2) and all its dependencies probably already loads more than 1MB.

Comment: @liberforce Agreed. If you want to keep the memory down, GTK and Qt are not the way to go. If you want to say "to hell with Gtk, accessibility and the fact that users with small screens won't be able to see your cancel buttons" then bypass the display manager completely and write it in something like X11.

Comment: @adimetrius Also, if you're already using GTK+ in the first place, then use a "real" layout widget instead of GtkFixed. It won't require more memory. GtkFixed might be of some in very specific use cases (embedded, fixed size screen), but otherwise, doesn't cover most features a user expects from an app in 2019 (like a non-broken fullscreen mode). Make it as simple as possible, but not simpler.